# onChange event not firing on mobile and smaller devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slate

I am trying to integrate the slate js editor [here](https://www.slatejs.org/#/rich-text)
in my app and have successfully done that. Every is working fine . However, i noticed my state or value doesn't get set on mobile and smaller devices. Upon investigation and debugging, i realised the `onChange` event doesn't fire on mobile and smaller devices until i click the `enter` key. My state or value get updated only when i click enter key, otherwise whatever text i entered doesn't trigger the `onChange` event. I confirmed that `onInput` event does get fired, however, it doesn't expose the value within the event. Please is there any way to circumvent this issue on mobile ? What is stopping onChange event from triggering on smaller devices and how do i fix this pls ?

Comment: The `onChange` event occurs when an element loses focus or the enter key is pressed, given that the value has been altered. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: @Matthew yes, i understand that. But without that i can't update my text, i am searching for alternative on slate js. I have been trying to utilised the onIput event to no avail.

Comment: `onchange` is case sensitive.

Comment: @NuruSalihu maybe try looking into `onKeyup` or `onBlur` as another fix?

Comment: I was thinking, why not hack it in a way to automatically press the enter key for someone? So an event that would fire after 2 seconds to see if they haven’t typed and if there has been no modification s and that the user is there focused on that, it’ll just press enter on behalf of the user.  Does that sound like a possible solution? I know it may not be what you want, but maybe be a fix for your mobile issue.